# Chrome pops up User/password box twice - httpd - Kerberos

Tags: kerberos, httpd.conf

we have a app runnng on Httpd and kerberos authentication. Whenever we want to logon the app from chrome, the user/password dialog box pop up twice always,irrespective of correct or incorrect login info.

>

Comment: I have location paramter twice inside httpd directory. is that matter?

Comment: Are you using the IP address of your server when reaching your app ? Or the name / a DNS of your server ? Kerberos authentication does not support IP address url.